# How to convert a method into a scope.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello I am trying to convert the method `self.liked_by(user)` into a scope. I am not entirely sure what my instructor is asking for so any interpretations on the question are greatly appreciated.

this is the method in question that I am supposed to turn into a scope.

```
def self.liked_by(user)
    joins(:likes).where(likes: { user_id: user.id })
end
```

this is where the method appears in the model

```
class Bookmark < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :topic
  has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
  before_validation :httpset
  validates :url, format: { with: /\Ahttp:\/\/.*(com|org|net|gov)/i,
    message: "only allows valid URLs." }

  def self.liked_by(user)
    joins(:likes).where(likes: { user_id: user.id })
  end

  def  httpset
    if self.url =~ /\Ahttp:\/\/|\Ahttps:\/\//i
    else
      if self.url.present?
        self.url = "http://"+ self.url
      else
        self.url = nil
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And this is where the method is called in the controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    @bookmarks = user.bookmarks
    @liked_bookmarks = Bookmark.liked_by(user)
  end
end
```

Thanks for looking at my problem and have a good day.

Comment: Without giving the answer away directly... please read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

Comment: Here is an somewhat older but great article on the slight differences between working with scopes vs. class methods: http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/02/active-record-scopes-vs-class-methods/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@liked_bookmarks = Bookmark.liked_by(user)`

In this line, in the same way you send the `user parameter` to a `method`, the same way you can send it to a `scope`.

```
class Bookmark < ActiveRecord::Base
   ---------
   ---------
   scope :liked_by, ->(user) { joins(:likes).where(likes: { user_id: user.id }) }
   ---------
   ---------
  end
```

the parameter you sent from the scope call can be accessed using the (user{or any name) in the scope

[reference of scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes)

Answer (score 2):

As Owen suggested, read [the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) to understand what scopes are. It is just another syntax to define your model's class methods (just like the one you already have).

```
scope :liked_by, ->(user) { joins(:likes).where(likes: { user_id: user.id }) }
```